# menu populated from database

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a side navigation populated from the database. I want the categories to show up on the left hand side and when you click on one the others slide down to make room for the sub categories. However I am having trouble getting them to work properly.

I got the main categories up and running and got it to slide down and display a subcategory hard coded saying "hello world" but now i am trying to populate the sub categories with those from the database I am having trouble getting it all to work.

Here is my code:

**this is my database connection**

```
<?php 
    $base = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
        $mysql_connection = db_connect_enhanced('*********','dbaccess','*******','website');    //Connect to database
        $categories = "SELECT * FROM *********** WHERE active = 1";
        $result = db_query_into_array_enhanced($mysql_connection, $categories);
        $count = count($result);
?>
```

**Here is the code to display my navigation**

```
    <div id="left-prod-nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="top">Product Categories</li>
            <?for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
            {?> 
            <div class="flip"><li><img src="images/arrowright_off.gif" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;float:right;"><a href="#"><?=$result[$i]['categoryName']?></a></li> </div>
                    <? $subCategories = "SELECT * FROM ************* WHERE active = 1";
                    $subCatResult = db_query_into_array_enhanced($mysql_connection, $subCategories);
                    $subCount = count($subCatResult);
                    for($i = 0; $i < $subCount; $i++) 
                    {?>
                        <div class="panel"><?=$subCatResult[$i]['categoryName']?></div>
                    <?}?>

            <?}?>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
```

**Here is the javascript that gets the navigation to slide down and up on click**

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".flip").click(function(){
            $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

as i said, getting the top tier nav to work was fine. it displayed the categories from the database and slid down when clicked. but now im trying to display the sub categories when it slides down I cant.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you surrounding your LI with a DIV???  That's not valid markup!

Comment: is that what is causing my problem?

Comment: No, I don't think so, just an observation.

Comment: define your base as `$base = '/';`

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to several things in your code

1.In you query , you are setting

```
SELECT * FROM ************* WHERE active = 1
```

How it will differentiate the parent category ? Check For: Is it returning value ?

2.May be CSS problem too, can you check for `.panel { ... }` in your css

3.You closed your Flip Div at the catagory name itself, complete it after panel is over

```
  <?}?>
      <?}?>
          </div> //Flip div
              </ul>
```

4.Pl try this plain html and check if it works, then you can confirm , which error...is it db or jquery :)
Try this:

```
<div id="left-prod-nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="top">Product Categories</li>
            <div class="flip"><li><img src="images/arrowright_off.gif" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;float:right;"><a href="#">categoryName</a></li> </div>
             <div class="panel">c1</div>
             <div class="panel">c2</div>
             <div class="panel">c3</div>
              <div class="panel">c4</div>         
        </ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: ok that point you made about differentiating the parent categories makes some sense. but how do I do that? how do i get to to display the subcategories for category1 when I click that?

Comment: In the DB, create two tables[Table1]-> mcid | main_category_Name and in second table create [Table2]-> sub_cata_name | mcid(from table1) ... so take sub category by "SELECT * FROM  table2 where mcid='1'" for Main Category [1] :)

Comment: i know this. but this doesnt help...if i can explain it right...I have a vertical navigation down the left hand side. its populated from the database. so ive selected all main categories and then displayed them down the left hand side. they are in a category table. now i have sub categories for them. stored in a sub category table. they are linked via their IDs as you suggest. now I need to display those sub categories underneath the main category when it is clicked. no linking to new page, just javascript sliding down the navigation to make room for the sub categories...how is this done?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="left-prod-nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="top">Product Categories
            <ul class="categories">
                <?for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {?> 
                <li class="flip">
                    <a href="#"><?=$result[$i]['categoryName']?></a>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <? $subCategories = "SELECT * FROM ************* WHERE active = 1";
                        $subCatResult = db_query_into_array_enhanced($mysql_connection, $subCategories);
                        $subCount = count($subCatResult);
                        for($i = 0; $i < $subCount; $i++) { ?>
                        <a href="<?=$subCatResult[$i]['categoryLink']?>"><?=$subCatResult[$i]['categoryName']?></a><br />
                        <?}?>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?}?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li.flip > a").click(function() {
        // hide all others
        $("div.panel").slideUp();
        // show the relevant one
        $("div.panel", $(this)).stop().slideDown();
    });
});
</script>
```

You need to alter your html structure. This is a suggestion of how I'd do it (untested code).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3bM2K/ -- this is the code working (with a minor fix to the code above). It's an accordion-style menu, which is what I think you were aiming for.